# How can I calculate the cost of the Loan with the Capital and interest rate? Vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I’m doing a Intership as a Developer an got a tough exercise. I’ve got a Loan Text and there are 3 Fields blank, the Loan, the Capital and the interest rate. I’ve created already the and it look like this:

```
    Private Sub l_jahre_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub txt_abtrag_Change()
    CalculateFormular
End Sub

Private Sub txt_darlehen_Change()
    CalculateFormular
End Sub

Private Sub txt_zinssatz_Change()
    CalculateFormular
End Sub

Private Sub CalculateFormular()
    If (validate()) Then
        Debug.Print "Success"
    End If
End Sub


Private Function validate() As Boolean
    validate = True
    On Error GoTo x
    a = CDbl(txt_abtrag.Value) + CDbl(txt_darlehen.Value) + CDbl(txt_zinssatz.Value)
    Exit Function
x:
    validate = False
End Function

Public Sub test2()
    'Debug.Print txt_zinssatz.Value
    l_zinsen.Caption = "inf."
End Sub
```

Don’t mind the Value of them xd

And now I Need to calculate, like I said, the cost of the Loan with the Capital and interest rate.

I Need to fill it up and it Looks like this.

```
Public Function GetTotalCost(ByVal capital As Double, ByVal rate As Double) As Double
    GetTotalCost = 0
End Function

Public Function GetRentTime(ByVal capital As Double, ByVal rate As Double, ByVal monthPay As Double) As Double
    GetRentTime = 0
End Function
```

please don’t say the full Code or the full answer I just Need some help to understand and what method I should use.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you have problems with VBA or with the math?

Comment: with the vba. I know the math

Comment: And where are you stuck? Writing some lines of math calculation should be pretty easy.

Comment: But i don´t have a clue how i can do it. The only Thing i know is that i have to use "txt_Loan.Value , txt_capital.value and txt_capitalinterest.value"

Comment: Do you even know where these inputs are coming from? Do you know how to deal with variables - in any programming language?

Answer (score 0):

The financial formulae below each solve one financial argument (PV, FV, PMT, NPER) in terms of the others, using `(pmt*nper)+pv+fv = 0` if the rate is 0, and `pv*((1+rate)^nper)+pmt*(1+rate*type)*((1+rate)^nper-1)/rate+fv = 0` otherwise, where:

• pv is the present value of a loan or investment, and represents the current value of a series of future payments. For example, when you borrow money, the amount you owe is the present value to the lender.

• fv is the future value, or a cash balance of the loan or investment after the last payment is made.

• rate is the interest rate per period.

• nper is the total number of payment periods over the life of the loan or investment.

• pmt is the fixed instalment paid in each period. The instalment amount usually includes components to cover both principal and interest but may not include loan fees etc. This is negative if you're borrowing, because it represents money you would pay (i.e. a negative cash flow).

• type is the number 0 or 1 and indicates when instalments are paid. 0 indicates payments are made at the end of the period, 1 indicates payments are made at the start of the period. Equally, some loans charge interest on the basis of the amount outstanding at the beginning of the period, whilst others charge interest on the basis of the amount outstanding at the end of the period.

Solving for the future value, the formula is:

```
fv=-if(rate=0,pmt*nper+pv,(pv*((1+rate)^nper)+pmt*(1+rate*type)*((1+rate)^nper-1)/rate))
```

Solving for the present value, the formula is:

```
pv=-if(rate=0,pmt*nper+fv,(fv+pmt*(1+rate*type)*((1+rate)^nper-1)/rate)/((1+rate)^nper))
```

Solving for the payment value, the formula is:

```
pmt=-if(rate=0,(pv+fv)/nper,(pv*((1+rate)^nper)+fv)/((1+rate*type)*((1+rate)^nper-1)/rate))
```

Solving for the number of periods, the formula is:

```
nper=-if(rate=0,(pv+fv)/pmt,(log(1+(pv+pmt*type)/pmt*rate)-log(1+(fv+pmt*type)/pmt*rate))/log(1+rate))
```

Solving for the interest rate, the formula is:

```
rate=(fv/pv)^(1/nper)-1
```

*provided pmt is 0*. Otherwise, you can only solve for the interest rate through iteration (eg using one of the above formulae).